# VSCode TSLint Menu Icon

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I have several ts projects in angular and react. I've encountered some issues trying to get tslint to run in VSCode. In trying to get to the bottom of this, I've noticed that sometimes the TSLint icon shows up in the bottom bar of VSCode, and sometimes it does not.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ebn1.jpg)

I have no idea what setting/config determines whether this icon shows up. I also don't know if the absence of this icon indicates that tslint is not configured for that project within VSCode. Please could someone let me know what causes this icon to show up in any given project. Thanks!

Comment: In my brief testing, the icon showed up as long as I had the TSLint extension enabled in the VS Code extension manager, had the `tslint.enable` setting set to `true` (which is the default), and opened a `.ts` file.  Have you checked these things?  Does the "Log (Extension Host)" output window indicate that the `eg2.tslint` extension is being activated?